# Maximum Minimum theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Whether a continuous function defined on a half open bounded interval either attains maximum or minimum. 
Tried to find a proof or a counter example. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want something that attains neither a maximum nor a minimum on $[0,1)$, try and picture a function $f(x)$ that will oscillate between larger and larger positive and negative values as $x\to 1$.

Answer (score 0):

On a half closed interval a continuous function  need not be bounded above or below. For example, on $(0,1]$ the function $\frac 1 x \sin(\frac 1 x)$ is neither bounded above nor bounded below. 
 Even  if $f$ is bounded it need not attain its maximum or minimum: for $n$ even consider a non-negative continuous function on $[\frac 1 {n+1} \frac 1 n]$ vanishing at the end points with maximum value $1-\frac 1 n$. for $n$ odd consider a non-positive continuous function on $[\frac 1 {n+1} \frac 1 n]$ vanishing at the end points with minimum value $-(1-\frac 1 n)$. The functions together define  a continuous function which neither attains its maximum nor attains its minimum.

Comment: Both functions attains either maximum or minimum on a given half open bounded interval. My question is does it always hold

Comment: Thank you for answer

Comment: @user574351 I have added some more information to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

We can easily design a function that does not attain either its maximum or its minimum, by placing it at the "missing" endpoint. Like

$$(0,4]\to\pm\frac1{1+x^2}.$$

But we can as well achieve both maximum and minimum at the missing point by modulating with an alternating function with an infinity of extrema that converge to the missing point. Like

$$(0,4]\to\frac{\sin\dfrac1x}{1+x^2}.$$

[image]